# How to Read ChildNode

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I really need help. I can't solve it.
I want to read data from Xml File.
This is the Xml File

```
<ARTICLE>
    <ARTICLE_FEATURES>
                <REFERENCE_FEATURE_SYSTEM_NAME>ECLASS-5.1</REFERENCE_FEATURE_SYSTEM_NAME>
                <FEATURE>
                    <FNAME>Verpackungseinheit</FNAME>
                    <FVALUE>100</FVALUE>
                    <FUNIT>Box</FUNIT>
                </FEATURE>
                <FEATURE>
                    <FNAME>Farbe</FNAME>
                    <FVALUE>weiss</FVALUE>
                </FEATURE>
                <FEATURE>
                    <FNAME>Material</FNAME>
                    <FVALUE>Latex gepudert</FVALUE>
                </FEATURE>
</ARTICLE>
```

I reading like this

```
 var productQuery = (from p in xmlDocument.Descendants("ARTICLE")
                                select new
                                {
                                    Names = p.Element("ARTICLE_FEATURES").Elements("FEATURE").Select(s => s.Element("FNAME").Value)
                                    groupName = (p.Element("ARTICLE_FEATURES").Elements("FEATURE").Count() > 0) ? p.Element("ARTICLE_FEATURES").Elements("FEATURE").Select(s => s.Value) :
                                    value = (p.Element("ARTICLE_FEATURES").Elements("FEATURE").Count() > 0) ? p.Element("ARTICLE_FEATURES").Element("FEATURE").Element("FVALUE").Value : string.Empty
};
```

But it is not working and none of these elements (FEATURE) in some products Therefore necessary as to check whether. There are multiple elements Also for a product If I use inline operator In this case I do not know How do I do the other part.

> Both the same I wrote once more to show How I did it.  (Names ==
>   groupName )

Comment: why don't you just deserialize it to strongly typed object in C#?

Comment: @AmitKumarGhosh I dont know too much How to do Xmlserializer it.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this using `Linq` to `Xml`.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);

var results = doc.Descendants("ARTICLE_FEATURES")   //look for descendants
                  .Select(x=>new 
                   {
                       Names = x.Elements("FEATURE").Select(e=>e.Element("FNAME").Value).ToList(),  // look for nested eleements.
                       Value = x.Elements("FEATURE").Select(e=>e.Element("FVALUE").Value).ToList(),
                   });
```

Check this [`Demo`](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YNbBbM)